Movie (or tv show) from 80s or 90s about school kid who makes a computer program come alive
It was probably american, they talked english at least.
There is a computer class, and one of the students either cause or notice that his computer program starts communicating with him on his screen, and in the middle of the movie the program needs to hide, and moves about on the school network.
The computers are text only, no GUIs or fancy gfx as I can remember.
In the end, he thinks the program has been erased, but it appears when he is to get money from an ATM where it tells him "Long time no see" which he immediately realizes is the same program talking to him and that it has escaped the school.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.  Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
